# How to disable trailing slash redirect in Symfony 4.1?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony4

I'd like to disable [default Symfony 4.1 behavior](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html) that redirects users from `/foo/` to `/foo`. What's the best way to disable this behavior? I'm developing API so I don't need these redirects.

Comment: So what do you want to happen if GET /foo/ is requested but is not defined?  As long as the requested path is defined then there will be no redirects.

Comment: I'd like to return 404 for all requests that contain trailing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@NicolasB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10408843/nicolasb)'s solution is too hacky, so I've created custom event listener that checks all responses with redirects and converts them to 404 error:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class RedirectionListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        if ($response->isRedirection()) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register it:

```
App\EventListener\RedirectionListener:
  tags:
  - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response }
```

Note: all redirects will be converted to 404s, not only trailing slash redirects. You should keep it in mind. However I am developing API, so I don't need any redirects at all, so this solution solves my problem.

If you know better solution you're welcome to post another reply!

Answer (score 1):

If you know that *every single route* that ends with a trailing slash should generate a 404, you could simply define a route which does:

```
/**
 * @Route("{anything}/")
 */
public function routeWithTrailingSlashAction()
{
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
}
```

I assume there might be a more proper way to do that, but I think it should work at least as a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

To improve NicolasB's answer, I guess checking the slash on each request in a single EventSubscriber would do the trick. While still being a bit sneaky, this solution seems way more maintainable to me.